# @import "compass" always cause errors

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, compass

I am using Windows 7 with latest ruby installed. Whenever I use

```
@import "compass"
```

in the scss file, Compass fails to compile the file. And compass always gives me

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory -
>   C:/Users/chcheng/Test/www/.sass-cache/75fcaf1b4852ceb732871195e41567cc2a7d8997/C%058%092Ruby200-x64%092lib%092ruby%092gems%0922.0.0%092gems%092compass-core-1.0.1%092stylesheets%092compass%092utilities%092general%092_hacks.scssc20140903-4052-1h721dg

I tried to uninstall compass and sass as well as the whole ruby.... but it doesn't solve my problem.

Can anyone tell me how the problem can be solved?

Comment: `@impost` or `@import` ? rugby or ruby ? Window7 or Windows 7 ?

Comment: Possibly related to this issue:  https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1406

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue. My problem is related to the length of the .sass-cache file full path. If the length of the path exceeds 255, compile will fail.

The solution is to set a shorter cache path. You may configure the cache path in config.rb by using:

```
cache_path = "C:/temp/sass/"
```

Related issue:
https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1791